# Segmentation fault(core dumped)/Signal Real-time 45

Tags: unix

I have to write an application that will stream some book to many clients. While writing i met a problem with Segmentation fault. I know that when it is being killed SIG45 is being sent. Here is my code.

Server code:http://wklej.org/id/3365150/
Client code:http://wklej.org/id/3365151/

Problem occurs when i run first client. Could you please tell what am i doing wrong here?

I run my example with gdb and this is what i got.
Program received signal SIG45, Real-time event 45.
main (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffde28) at serverA.c:172
172     while(1) {}